# Cannot add jars to new Docker image using gradle-docker-plugin

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration

I'm almost new to Docker and Gradle. I'm building my own CI process using Docker, Gradle and Jenkins.

**What I want:**

Executing a build on Jenkins executes my Gradle build script containing gradle-docker plugin(palantir) so it then builds a corresponding Docker image.

**What I've done:**

My Docker image to be built has to contain an executable jar file(Spring-boot), so I've added a Docker build step, ADD to my Dockerfile to add my jar file created by the build task of the same Gradle build process to my new Docker image.

The docker build context directory created by Gradle is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/build_test_docker/build/docker
```

The above directory initially has only the Dockerfile. So I copied the jar that I want to add via an Execute shell step in Jenkins, like this:

```
cp ${WORKSPACE}/build/libs/*jar ${WORKSPACE}/build/docker/
```

But I failed because of-

**What I've encountered**:

I got the following error:

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder498743832/gs-spring-boot-docker.jar: no such file or directory
```

The main cause of the above error I figured out is the gradle-docker plugin unexpectedly removes the docker directory containing the jar file that is supposed to be added to the new Docker image and creates a new docker directory that has only the Dockerfile.

What should I do for this problem? I think there would be a simple and great approach to solve the problem even without using execute shell copy step.

Comment: did you add the `files` parameter to the [Docker config](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker#docker-plugin)

Comment: @nlloyd Ah! thank you! that was the point I was missing. You saved my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nlloyd's comment, the key to the problem was my Dockerfile setting.

The following is the key part in my Gradle script with the problem.

```
...
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files jar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${jar.archiveName}"])
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}
...
```

It creates the jar file as follows:

```
.../build/libs/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar
```

and the following is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

It takes an argument, 'JAR_FILE' that is supposed to be the full path of the jar file to be included in the new Docker image to be built and the specific value of JAR_FILE is specified by the docker task in the Gradle script through '${jar.archiveName}'.

The following is the error message I got during docker task.

```
ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder498743832/gs-spring-boot-docker.jar: no such file or directory
```

It attempts to add **'.../gs-spring-boot-docker.jar'**, but the actual name of the jar file is **'gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar'**, followed by the version signature.

so I've removed the 'version' in bootJar in the Gradle script:

```
bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
}
```

Then it creates a jar file with the correct name, **'gs-spring-boot-docker.jar'** and the build process is successfully completed.

I don't know yet there is a better way of doing this, but the problem is done.